# javascript iframe contents loading issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one `Iframe` in my website.I initialized it `src` at `document.ready event`. I placed `iframe` inside the `jquery UI` dialog, now every time when we open the dialog, Iframe load its contents, but i want that this loading process happens only once at `document.ready`.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can fetch once the content using an XmlHttpRequest, store it into a local variable and reuse this variable when you open the dialog.

```
var myReusableContent;

$(window).ready(function() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                myReusableContent = httpRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', muurl);
    httpRequest.send();
});
```

When you need to fill the iframe, simply do

```
$('myIframe').html(myReusableContent);
```

Comment: In my case i cant use `$('myIframe').html(myReusableContent);` this to fill the iframe because the document which i am loading have some script which conflicts with the `iframe` parent document, so is there any other way to fill the iframe

Comment: What's your exact goal ? Why do you want to fetch the document only once ?

Comment: because i am modifying it on the client side, so for save the change i have to load it only once

Comment: I suggest you use an ajax logic : fetch data (in json for example), store those data in js variable, and build the html using the data.